# Check whether the array contains more than 1 equivalent value

Tags: java, android

I have an array where i get the values as names of some students and the array is dynamically populates and it does not contain static values. Now what i want to check is that whether the array obtained has any same name. Here is some part of my code,

```
       ArrayList<Student> rows;

         for (Student name: rows) {

        }
```

I dont know how to check. I have used compartor but it didnt work. Can anyone help. Inside the array I will get all student names

Comment: What does the Student class look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a list to store any duplicate names:

```
List<String> dups = new ArrayList<>();
```

and a set where you will store names:

```
Set<String> names = new HashSet<>();
```

A set contains only unique values.  
Now iterate through your list 
(I guess your `Student` class has a method like `getName()` to obtain the student's name):

```
for (Student student : rows) {
    String studentname = student.getName(); 
    if (!names.add(studentname) {
        dups.add(studentname);
    }
}
```

The method `names.add()` returns `false` when it's not possible for an item to be added to the set because it already exists in it. 
So when it returns `false` it encountered a duplicate name and the name is added to the `dups` list.
When this loop finishes, you can find all the duplicate student names in the `dups` list and show them in a toast:

```
    if (dups.size() > 0) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("There are duplicates: ");
        for (String studentname : dups) {
            sb.append(studentname).append(", ");
        }
        String msg = sb.toString();
        msg = msg.substring(0, msg.length() - 2);
        Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

- Store the data in HashMap with key as studentName and value as student object

  Map studentMap = new HashMap<>()
- If you add the data with same key again , the data gets updated

  studentMap.put(studentName, Student)
- To check if key exists and update accordingly

  if(studentMap.containsKey(studentName)){
        // logic if key already exists
     }else{
       //logic if key doesn't exists
     }
- If you want list instead of map , then get list from map

  List studentList = new ArrayList(studentMap.values())

Comment: I didnt get you. I want to show a toast if the list cotains same values. How will i know the values repeated

Comment: check if key exists by    if(studentMap.containsKey(studentName)){   // logic if key already exists } else { //logic if key doesn't exists }

Answer (score 0):

A way to check it is to convert your list to a set and check if the size got reduced (because `Set`s do not accept duplicate values), something like :

```
ArrayList<Student> rows;

    Set<Student> set = new HashSet<Student>(rows);

    if(set.size() < rows.size()){
       // In this case you have repeated values in the list
    }
```

Note that it depends on your `equals` method of the `Student` class to determine how Students are compared, so since you are checking againist their names you might have this  `equals` method inside your `Student` class:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if( obj instanceof Student) {
        return (obj.name.equals(name));
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Check this sample java class used to count no of duplicate elements.**

```
 public class CountDuplicate {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

            arrayList.add("aaa");  
            arrayList.add("bbb"); 
            arrayList.add("aaa");
            arrayList.add("bbb");
            arrayList.add("ccc");  
            arrayList.add("bbb");  
            arrayList.add("ccc");  
            arrayList.add("aaa");
            arrayList.add("ccc");  
            arrayList.add("bbb");

            HashSet<String> hsUnique = new HashSet<String>(arrayList);

            for (String str : hsUnique) {
                System.out.println(Collections.frequency(arrayList, str) +" times "+ str);
            }
        }
    }
```